# Unable to access EJB in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, ejb

My EJB is as follows and deployed on Glassfish with JNDI name (retrieved from Glassfish console) - **java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean!com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/AdminOperationsBean")
public class AdminOperationsBean implements AdminOperationsBeanRemote { }
```

In my Spring project, I am trying to access the bean. ApplicationContext.xml is as follows - 
    `<jee:remote-slsb id="adminRemote"
    jndi-name="java:global/FinalEJBProject-
    ejb/AdminOperationsBean!com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote"
    business-interface="com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote"
    cache-home="false" lookup-home-on-startup="false"
    refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true" />`

In Spring controller -

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

private AdminOperationsBeanRemote adminRemote;

public void setAdminOperationsBeanRemote(AdminOperationsBeanRemote 
adminRemote) {
this.adminRemote = adminRemote;
}

public AdminOperationsBeanRemote getAdminOperationsBeanRemote() {
return adminRemote;
}
```

I am always getting a lookup failed -

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Failed to locate remote EJB [java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean!com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote]; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean!com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: FinalEJBProject-ejb]
```

Can someone please help me, I have been on this for the past three days!

Comment: The mappedName attribute is for a product specific name. Instead use the name attribute. If you want to access an EJB bean inside to you app, the jndi lookup looks like this : java:comp/env/ejb/beanname[/interfacename]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out,in your ApplicationContext.xml use the JNDI name without the suffix qualifier name.

```
java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean!com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote

java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean
```

Use the second JNDI name in the ApplicationContext.xml as follows -

`<jee:remote-slsb id="adminRemote"
    jndi-name="java:global/FinalEJBProject-ejb/AdminOperationsBean"
           business-
    interface="com.humber.its.n01131590.AdminOperationsBeanRemote"
           cache-home="false" lookup-home-on-startup="false"
           refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true" />`